# Adding a favicon to an existing hugo theme

Tags: html, themes, netlify, hugo

I'm trying to add a favicon to the following hugo theme: https://github.com/stackbithq/stackbit-theme-fjord The problem is that the documentation points me to a [Gatsby.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) example.

I've generated the favicon assets and placed them within */static*, where does the following markup need to be placed within the theme?

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

For reference, I tried creating a head section within *header.html* but this wasn't generating the favicon while testing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the lines to the file `components/html_head.html`

```
...
{% if site.params.favicon %}
<link rel="icon" href="{{ site.params.favicon | relative_url }}">
{% endif %}
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

Comment: thanks, it also looks like I was using an older version of the template which didn't provide this piece.